# Setting up Route53 alias - "website_domain" deprecation warning

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform, alias

I have a static website hosted on s3.

Please reference my route53 alias setup and deprecation warning below:

terraform config block for route53:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
  name = var.static_web_bucket
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  name    = var.static_web_bucket

  # setting up a DNS A record 
  type = "A"
  alias {
    # exported attribute for the domain of the website endpoint
    name = aws_s3_bucket.cloud_cv.website_domain
    # exported attribute for the Route 53 Hosted Zone ID for this bucket's region.
    zone_id                = aws_s3_bucket.cloud_cv.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

deprecation warning

```
│ Warning: Deprecated attribute
│ 
│   on route53.tf line 13, in resource "aws_route53_record" "www":
│   13:     name = aws_s3_bucket.cloud_cv.website_domain
│ 
│ The attribute "website_domain" is deprecated. Refer to the provider
│ documentation for details.
│ 
│ (and one more similar warning elsewhere)
```

The [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket) for `aws_s3_bucket` resource state "website_domain" is n exported attribute and they don't state the attribute has been depracated. Should I reference the `bucket_domain_name` instead?

What I am trying to acheive is to have the following alias point to my s3 website: `firstname-lastname-cloud-cv.com`.

For reference to versions used please see below:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~>4.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a completely new resource for this since provider version 4: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_website_configuration. Look at the attributes that are exported.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that they are missing some documentation about that. I had to do some searching to understand why the deprecation warning was happening. It appears that the entire `aws_s3_bucket` `website` configuration block is deprecated. So it is now deprecated to configure website settings in the `aws_s3_bucket` resource, and thus it is deprecated to reference those settings as well.

The new method is to use a separate [aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_website_configuration) resource, and you would access the `website_domain` attribute on that resource.